# Infinite Scrolling With Already-Loaded Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, infinite-scroll

So most infinite scrolling I've seen has to do with elements that are already paginated. It basically makes an ajax call to the next page and displays that when the window reaches a certain breaking point.

I'm dealing with code that has 100 light-weight divs already loaded on the page, but, for UI purposes, we want to lazy-load the divs as they are scrolled to instead of showing them all at once. The basic structure looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
     some other html
  </div>
  <div class="element">
     some other html
  </div>
  <div class="element">
     some other html
  </div>
  <div class="element">
     some other html
  </div>
  .... 100 times
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this? The jscroll plugin seems like it should work, but when I try the following js:

$('.container').jscroll();

It seems to think that I don't want to implement the lazy loading until the end of the entire container. When I reach the end of the container, the page crashes. If I bind jscroll to the 'element' class, all hell breaks loose and it's clearly not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So: you want placeholder divs instead of the real content. The length of the scrollbar should be maxed out from the start and when a div comes into view you will load the content.

It's important that you know how high each div is, else you can render a suitable placeholder.

If you've got that, add a scroll listener to the scroll container. Every time you scroll, figure out which divs are in the viewport (by looking at `.scrollTop` and `height` and position offsets of the placeholder divs. Then load the content for the divs.